# Dotfill inside enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I am trying to add questions to a book that I am writing so I can not use the exam document class.

I thought a work round would be to write the questions as part of the enumerate environment but when I add a new line and try to dot fill it comes back with an error.

```
\begin{enumerate}
    \item What is the name of your dog? 
\newline \dotfill

\end{enumerate}
```

I wanted it to look like this,

1) What is the name of your dog?

.....................................................

Comment: Do you want the dot fill after each item, or at the end of the list only?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

    \begin{enumerate}[wide]
        \item What is the name of your dog?\\[2ex]
        \mbox{}\dotfill 
    \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]